# Is there a limit on upvotes?

Tags: support, reputation, voting

Just curiousity really, but I noticed in the recent days that one of my posts [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020) get plus/minus 10 point votes recently (which I find a bit surprising) - could it be that I have hit an absolute limit with 420  plus votes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the [ceiling is far higher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/914686)... if there exists one.

What's happening is that some users have un-upvoted your answer and then re-upvoted it. Looking at [your reputation for today](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10109/frank-mittelbach?tab=reputation), you'll see the following:

[image]

The -10 reputation stems from an un-upvote (actually upvoted on a different day) while it seems the un-upvote was immediately rectified (seconds apart) with a re-upvote. The re-upvote, of course, cancels the unnecessary un-upvote.

Comment: [Unfortunately un-up/down-votes are not included in SEDE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246294/168244)...

Comment: 10-10+10-10+10-10... does not converge